Web service references not available after migration from xamarin.android to .net8.0 android
I am migrating my xamarin android app to the new .net8.0 framework. This is a nightmare of a task and I have almost completed it apart from migrating my web references successfully.
On my previous older version of the app in xamarin I was able to consume my webservice as a connected web service and the import created the classes and framework easily.
Now it appears all I am getting is an interface style soap client that I am struggling to get working correctly as I don't have experience in working with this type of webservice WCF.

In my older xamarin project the same service looked like this:

My issue now is in the older version I could declare:
using AXPackSlipService;

DeliveryNoteService testService = new DeliveryNoteService();

testService.getDeliveryNoteLines(string, string, string);

However
In the new .net8.0 where I try and add the exact same service reference I don't get the classes generated like I used to.
If I am able to correct instantiate the interface DeliveryNoteServiceSoap I can then access the method getDeliveryNoteLines as I did previously.
But I am struggling to achieve this, mainly due to lack of knowledge on how this process works vs previously where it appeared to be much easier.
How can I achieve what I need to work similarly as before.
Thanks
